# How should I deal with folders with "items as default view" in search results

Tags: plone

Are there any existing solutions to this issue: a folder with a page as a default view turns up in search results along with the page if both the titles have the same term. I.e. two results pointing to the same place.

I think this is a likely scenario, since the item used as default view essentially covers the folder's name, description etc, it is likely that they are named similarly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter out such results by filtering out default pages; simply set `is_default_page=False` to your catalog query. Alternatively, don't include the `Folder` type in your search.

This would remove default pages or the folders altogether; you'd have to manually filter if you don't want to show both `Folder` and their default page results if both are present.